# Set the Windows 10 OSK (on-screen keyboard) to different language than physical keyboard?

Tags: language, input-languages, accessibility, on-screen-keyboard

I use the Windows 10 on-screen keyboard to type Russian characters but I also need to use my physical English keyboard. Switching the input method back and forth is time consuming and inefficient. Even with the Windows shortcut of Windows key+Space bar, it is still too tedious.

Is there a way to keep the OSK (on-screen keyboard) set to the foreign language while keeping my physical keyboard as English? That would be the most convenient.

If that is not possible, is there a general consensus on best third-party software keyboard I could use? Ideally something free and open-source.

I am using Windows 10 version 1903.

Comment: I use the [Russian mnemonic keyboard layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/kbdrum.html) for typing Russian characters on my (latin letters based)  physical keyboard. Switching between them is easy via LeftAlt+Shift or Ctrl+Shift…